# How to add clang dependency to ROS package

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to release one ROS package,
but the automatic build of the package on Jenkins fails, with this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (project):
The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

 clang

is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (project):
The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

 clang++

is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

I understand that the problem is that clang is not installed in the docker container used by Jenkins to compile the package, but I don't know what to configure in the package to add this system dependency, I have tried to add both

```
<build_depend>clang</build_depend>
```

and

```
<buildtool_depend>clang<buildtool_depend>
```

but in both cases I have the error

```
KeyError: 'clang'
```

can someone please help me to understand how to add this system dependency?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344031/how-to-add-clang-dependency-to-ros-package/) by [codavide](https://answers.ros.org/users/51723/codavide/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you need to add a rosdep entry for clang: http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2020-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-13**:
Should we first wonder why the build is failing due to a missing Clang. By that I mean: is the OP specifically forcing the use of Clang? If so: why?